# Angular.js: Is it not possible to assign properties of a resolved promise to $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I am trying to refactor an application that has been using Ajax to fetch some serverdata and then attach it to `$rootScope` for controllers and services to pick up before bootstrapping the app and I have been trying to do so with promises using `$q`

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/22yQUlyE9nbQ0WVjxWxY

In that plnkr I am trying to have a service return some data for a few controllers to work with.

```js
app.service('data', function($q, $window, $timeout) {
   var promise = $q.defer();
   promise.promise.foo = 'Dang!';
   $timeout(function() {
     console.log('resolve promise');
     promise.resolve({
      foo: 'bar',
      baz: 'zot'
     });
   }, 1000);
   console.log('return promise');
   return promise.promise
});
```

I am using the resolve-property of $routeProvider like this

```js
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'MainController',
    templateUrl: 'data.html',
    resolve: {
      data: 'data'
    }
  });
});
```

But when I try to assign the 'foo' property of the resolved promise to $scope in one of my controllers it just comes out wrong.

```js
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.main = data.foo;
});

app.controller('Controller1', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.controller1 = data;
});
```

The `$scope` does not get updated when the promise resolves and the `foo` property of the actual promise object ends up on `$scope` as can be seen on http://plnkr.co/edit/22yQUlyE9nbQ0WVjxWxY?p=preview

So am I doing something I should absolutely not be doing here by assigning a property of a promise to `$scope`? I was under the impression that the resolve-property of the route meant that nothing was supposed to be initialized until the promise is resolved.

Comment: Seems you sometimes have top stop and re-run the plunker for the preview to actually work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is a timing issue.  When the service is instantiated, it sets a timeout.  Then the controllers are instantiated setting `$scope.main` to a property of `data`, but not to the object referenced by `data`.

When you assign this nested property to another reference, you lose the ability to track changes to the parent reference because this reference to the property will always be pointing at the old value.  You don't run into this problem when you reference the same object (`data`) in `Controller1` because the properties of the object pointed to by the reference are simply overwritten.  You would see the same problem if the resolve method was writing a new object to data, therefore changing the reference.

Broken into steps:

1) The data service is instantiated and has a returns an object with a single property `foo` pointing at a string object with the value `Dang!`.

2) The MainController is instantiated and sets the `main` property of the scope to be the object held in the foo property of the data service.  This is the important part because the main property only knows of the object `Dang!`.

Additionally, the Controller1 is instantiated and sets the `controller1` property of the scope to the object that is the data service.

3) The timer fires and overwrites the properties of the data object to some other properties.  Since the object at `data` wasn't replaced, `controller1` can see the new values at each of the properties.  Since `main` was pointing to the object which holds the value `Dang!`, nothing changes for it.  It would have only noticed changes if the object at it's reference had values change and since string values in javascript are immutable, there is no way for it to change.

To resolve your situation, if you want the properties of your scope to change with the service changes, you need to bind to your service and reference the properties in your expressions.

Comment: OK, so I guess the $q promise does not work exactly as I thought it would. I imagined that once the promise was resolved, angular would treat the promise as just a regular object. So what you're basically saying is that my controller is handed the future as soon as its declared and only delays actually reading it untill it is resolved after the timer?

Comment: Well, I phrased that a bit wrong, the controller is handed the reference to the future and that has a property that doesn't change on resolve. That explains what I am seeing.

Comment: That's exactly it.  The property is being overwritten on the `data` object when the resolve takes place by some new object, but the original assignment was a reference to the old object.